# How to remove an all the elements in an array through iteration

Tags: php, arrays, iteration

I have an array `$scripts_stack = [];` that holds arrays:

```
$array_item = array('script' => $file_parts, 'handle' => $file_name, 'src' => $url);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
```

---

```
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($scripts_stack); $i++) {
    $child_array = $scripts_stack[$i];
    if (is_array($child_array)) {
        // Do things with $child_array, 
        // then remove the child array from $scripts_stack when done with (BELOW)
        unset($scripts_stack[$i]);
    }
}

echo "Array Size : " . (sizeof($scripts_stack)); // AT THE END
```

However, my attemts only remove half the elements. No matter what I try, it's only half the items that get removed. `sizeof($scripts_stack)` is always half the size of what it was at the start.

I'm expecting that it would be empty **// AT THE END**

Why is it that I only get half the elements in the array removed?

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Use `foreach` Take a read here http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php#88578

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in other answers, `$i` increments but the `sizeof()` the array shrinks.  `foreach()` is probably the most flexible looping for arrays as it exposes the actual key (instead of hoping it starts at 0 and increments by 1) and the value:

```
foreach ($scripts_stack as $key => $child_array) {
    if (is_array($child_array)) {
        // Do things with $child_array, 
        // then remove the child array from $scripts_stack when done with (BELOW)
        unset($scripts_stack[$key]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just FYI, the way you're doing it with `for` *almost* works. You just need to establish the count before the loop definition, rather than recounting in the continuation condition.

```
$count = sizeof($scripts_stack);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {  // ...
```

Still, I think it would be better to just use a different type of loop as shown in the other answers. I'd personally go for `foreach` since it should always iterate every element even if some indexes aren't present. (With the way you're building the array, it looks like the indexes *should* always be sequential, though.)

Another possibility is to shift elements off of the array rather than explicitly unsetting them.

```
while ($child_array = array_shift($scripts_stack)) {
    // Do things with $child_array,
}
```

This will definitely remove every element from the array, though. It looks like `$child_array` should always be an array, so the `is_array($child_array)` may not be necessary, but if there's more to it that we're not seeing here, and there are some non-array elements that you need to keep, then this won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You advanced `$i` while the array is getting shrinked, but in the same time you jump over items in your array.

The first loop is where `$i == 0`, and then when you removed item 0 in your array, the item that was in the second place has moved to the first place, and your `$i ==` (so you will not remove the item in the current first place, and so on.

What you can do is use `while` instead of `for` loop:

```
<?php
$i = 0;
while ($i < sizeof($scripts_stack)) {
    $child_array = $scripts_stack[$i];
    if (is_array($child_array)) {
        // Do things with $child_array, 
        // then remove the child array from $scripts_stack when done with (BELOW)
        unset($scripts_stack[$i]);
    } else {
        $i++;
    }
}

echo "Array Size : " . (sizeof($scripts_stack)); // AT THE END
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use this script.It's not tested.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value ) {
    unset($array[$key]);
    echo $value." element is deleted from your array</br>";
}
```

I hope , it will help you.

Answer (score -3):

The problem root is in comparing `$i` with `sizeof($scripts_stack)`. Every step further `sizeof($scripts_stack)` becomes lower (it calculates at every step) and `$i` becomes higher.

The workaround may look like this:

```
<?php

$scripts_stack = [];

$array_item = array('script' => 1, 'handle' => 2, 'src' => 3);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);
array_push($scripts_stack, $array_item);

while (sizeof($scripts_stack) > 0) {
    $child_array = array_shift($scripts_stack);
    if (is_array($child_array)) {
        // Do things with $child_array, 
        // then remove the child array from $scripts_stack when done with (BELOW)
    }
}

echo "Array Size : " . (sizeof($scripts_stack)); // AT THE END
```

https://3v4l.org/N2p3v

Comment: Your original answer was wrong, and then you just copied what I wrote in my answer. Not so nice...